# What is the requirement for "single user only" option in AI Platform Notebooks on GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

In my environment, I have an AI Platform Notebooks instance for which I have configured single user access only. However, I am not able to SSH into it.

I have tried to make it work by granting the appropriate Cloud IAM roles. I granted both `iam/serviceAccountUser` and `iam/Project Editor` roles to a service account used for the instance. Since the instance does not have an external IP address, I have also granted `iam/IAP Tunnel User` role.

When the AI Platform Notebooks is created using the default service account, it is working fine. Obviously, I must be missing something granular. Is the restriction applied to the single user working, or what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

We have new IAM user permissions when you enable Notebooks API.

1. Enable Notebooks API
2. When you create a new Notebook,

a) From UI:

- Create a new Notebook > Customize > Permission > Single User Mode.

b) If using **gcloud compute** command: Make sure you use the following Metadata values are set:

```
proxy-mode: mail
proxy-user-mail: user@domain.com
```

c) If using **gcloud notebooks beta instances create** command passing metadata using `--metadata` option:

```
proxy-mode=mail, proxy-user-mail=user@domain.com
```

3. Grant user AI Notebooks IAM permissions on the IAM page.

In this case could be Notebooks Admin or Notebooks Runner.

Once that is done,

Verify your Metadata and make sure:

`enable-oslogin is set to TRUE`

For SSH Access:
Check:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#grant-iam-roles

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin/troubleshoot-os-login#checking_if_os_login_is_enabled

Note: I remember I needed to logout and login back before I was able to see the SSH button enabled and use Chrome.